# RX-JS - do we have in RX-JS method like .spy in bacon

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Is there any function in RX-JS that serve same as we have .spy in Bacon.js.
https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-spy

I need that to create Debugging tool for RX-JS.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use [`do`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) instance operator

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source.

For example

```
// do
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
  .do(
    // attach your function here
    function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }
  )
  .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

Comment: I can not use do operator because do is only work within chain of operators to observable or while defining an observable.

Comment: I can not use **do** operator because do is only work within chain of operators to observable or while defining an observable.   It did not work if i have something like this `code`     var myObs = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6]) .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });     AND then           myObs.do( // log function here) `code`